# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated equivalent in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using the default MVC 6 template in Visual Studio. I need to check if a user is authenticated in a class. This should be very simple but I cannot figure out why its not working.
Thanks in advance.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace fake.Classes
{
    public class fakeUser
    {
        public static string getBrand()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return getThemeName();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: asp.net-identity version? RC1? RC2? earlier?

Comment: "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final", thanks

Comment: Try with `context.User.Identities.Any(i => i.IsAuthenticated)`

Comment: User.Identity.IsAuthenticated works for me in rc1.final . What is your error message you get? Does the lighbulb icon not tell you what hte problem is

Comment: @Daniel Looks like adding context works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For the ASP.NET Core 1 version, you need to inject SignInManager to your controller via the consutructor, add that to a private signInManager field.

```
private SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
```

constructor:

```
SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager
_signInManager = signInManager;
```

then, you can use the signinmanager to check authentication:

```
_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User)
```

Comment: If using windows authentication, I get an exception UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_AuthenticationType() when calling this. Any thoughts on a method that is safe in either method? My app can be deployed either way.